How do I prove equivalence of two forms of Barcan formula?
Having a hard time proving the equivalence of two versions of the Barcan formula
Universal version:

∀x ◻Fx → ◻∀x Fx

Existential version:

◇∃x Fx → ∃x ◇Fx


I've tried two attempts:
1
∀x ◻Fx → ◻∀x Fx 
¬◻∀x Fx → ¬∀x ◻Fx (contrapositive)
◇∃x ¬Fx → ∃x ◇¬Fx (distribute negation over modal and quantification domains)
2
∀x ◻Fx → ◻∀x Fx 
¬ ∃x ¬◻Fx → ◻¬∃x¬Fx (universal/existential duality)
¬◻¬∃x¬Fx → ¬¬ ∃x ¬◻Fx (contrapositive) 
◇∃x ¬Fx → ∃x ◇ ¬Fx (necessity/potential duality)

In both cases above, I'm left with negated predicates, not the original predicates.
UPDATE: Based on @Mauro's helpful comments below, I see that we can use tautological implication to get the final result:

◇∃x ¬Fx → ∃x◇¬Fx (restatement)
F ← ¬F (generalization via substitution principle) 
◇∃x Fx → ∃x◇Fx (equivalent result)


Contraposition. Not necessary is Possibly not and Not forall is Exists not.

And yes, we read F as schematic and thus it hols also for not-F.

@MauroALLEGRANZA thank you! Regarding your first comment - I thought I did exactly that when forming the modus tollens version of universal barcan. Did I make a mistake? It would be great if I didn’t need to invoke schematic to get to the existential version.

@MauroALLEGRANZA sorry I’m not following— would you be able to post an answer to show how the two versions are equivalent? Or are you saying my derivation is correct?

@MauroALLEGRANZA see corollary at bottom of this page — seems like it’s simple but I’m not seeing how to get there https://plato.stanford.edu/archIves/sum2020/entries/actualism/proofBF.html

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I noticed that he also says the same for lemma 2 so I’m guessing he is treating results as schematic since modal logic isn’t truth functional anyway

Yes, IMO by prop logic means using tautological implication and using the def amounts to my initial comment above.

@MauroALLEGRANZA thank you so much! Apologies for being dense but does this mean all my steps were correct and all I’m missing is a final tautological implication?

Correct........

@MauroALLEGRANZA -- excellent! Thank you very much! super helpful :)

If you had done more calculus exercises you would have found this yourself :)

@mudskipper lol — yes, been over 20 years since i took real analysis
